# Jest unwantedly advancing timers with 50ms even though useFakeTimers is used

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm having a react native project, and I'm using jest to test. My jest version is 28.1.3. I'm using:

```
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.11",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.0.0",
```

I'm trying to mock an apollo client graphql query which uses a variable which is the current time, so I want to control the current time.

I'm using:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers({
      now: currentDate,
      advanceTimers: false,
    })
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
  });
```

However as I'm testing, I put a console log into the component I'm testing, and `Date.now()` is increasing by 50ms at every log.

I was using `waitFor` which I removed (have experience with it, and fake timers not being good friends), but it didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas what could cause the timers automatically advance?

Comment: Have the same issue. Would be cool to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

I found it was caused by Jest advancing mocked *clocks* by a default of 50ms whilst awaiting for the `findByXXX(..)` methods to complete. Jest uses https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sinonjs/fake-timers internally. This library mocks `Date.now()` with a *clock* that is treated no differently to any other "timer" and hence suffers from being advanced when it should not.

I fixed my problem by setting the `waitForOptions.interval` to 0.

```
expect(await findByTestId('tes-id', undefined, { interval: 0 })).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Subsequent use of `Date.now()` returned the same value as I'd originally set it when calling `jest.useFakeTimers({ now: new Date(2024, 0, 1) });`